# How to Delete or Update using SQLiteDatabase in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-delete

I have created a Database in MainActivity, and want to delete or update that Database in EditActivity with method below.

```
    private void deleteNote() {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("note.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS note("
            + "idx INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "name TEXT,"
            + "date TEXT,"
            + "taste TEXT,"
            + "rating FLOAT" + ");");
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM note WHERE idx = " + positionInt + ";");
    Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, "Delete Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.close();
}
```

Above is my deleting code, but it seems doesn't work right. I see the toast message("Delete Success"), however DB still has the deleted data.

My question is: 1) Are there any wrong part in my code? 2) Are there any way to check whether the data deleted or not in Android monitor, not using Virtual device?

Many thanks! Hope some guru help me out!

Comment: Of course, you see the toast, since it executes unconditionally. There's probably no record with `idx = " + positionInt`. Please understand that the position in a ListView (or any other list/grid-formic View) and a table row id are **not the same** thing. And they most likely will differ. By the way, the `;` at the end of a SQL query or command is **completely useless** (and string concatenation is a time consuming operation).

Comment: I had brought position number from ListView in MainActivity and defined it in EditActivity which I am working at. `Int positionInt = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", positionInt);` Thanks for letting me know semi colon is useless here!

Comment: `I had brought position number from ListView in MainActivity and defined it in EditActivity which I am working at.` Exactly what I understood. And, as I told you, the position in the ListView has **nothing to do** with the table row id.

Comment: @Rotwang Ok, now I understood. But I used the position number in ListView when I moved into the other activity. And the position number and the table row id is same. Then how can I make them connected?

Comment: The row id is most likely **nerver the same** as the ListView index. The IDs in a table start with **1**. A ListView item positions start with **0**. So you are at least *off by 1*. Not even to mention when you delete an item in the table. All the following row ids are not renumbered and new row ids will continue the count (this is so not to loose the eventual relations in other tables). You should retrieve the id in your **Adapter**.

Comment: @Rotwang I lacked the knowledge of SQLite Database in that it starts with 1! Thank you so much and I will try to fix it again. Thank you thank you!

Comment: Yes, but you can't rely on ListViiew items positions. They will always be numbered like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n` while items in a database table may have ids like `1, 5, 12, 47, 776, 1043, ..., m`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `db.delete()` instead, which also returns the number of affected rows that you could use for verification and show toast only when it works.

```
db.delete("tablename","id=?",new String[]{"1"});
```

Comment: I changed to "db.delete("note.db","'positionInt'",null);" and app is dead. Can you please tell me what to put in second and third position?(instead of "positionint" and null I am not sure of)